# RotateY and Perspective animation not working properly in chrome?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to rotate the image in y direction . My code is as follows

Js part

```
 $(function () {

      $("#content").click(function () {
          var css = {
              'transform': 'perspective(2000px) rotateY(-25deg )',
                  'transition-duration': '500ms'
          };
          $("#content").css(css);
      });
  });
```

CSS part

```
 #mainpage{
    height: 100%;
    width:100%;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;

  }
  #menubar{
    height: 100%;
    width:100px;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    background: #FF0000;
  }
  #content{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    background-image:url(images/clubs/Informals.jpg);
    background-size:100% 100%;
  }
```

HTML part

```
<div id="mainpage">
<div id="menubar"></div>
<div id="content"></div>
</div>
```

The code is working perfectly in firefox. But in chrome the perspective effect comes only after the animation is complete. In IE animation is not working it just changes to the final position. I tried adding the prefix '-webkit-' but still I am having the same problem.

Comment: As jsfiddle would help diagnose the issue

Answer (score -1):

You need yo use browser specific `-webkit-` for `transform`

```
transform:rotate(7deg);
-ms-transform:rotate(7deg); /* IE 9 */
-webkit-transform:rotate(7deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
```

To prevent your jquery becoming unmanagable I may be beneficial to put these values within a class and then just add the `class` rather than the `css`

Comment: There are lots of errors within your declaration, i'm surprised that it works in other browsers. Here is a clear way to declare them http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/dQ7J7/. You do not use `px` for `perspective`. Also `rotate` has a defualt of `Y` unless specified otherwise.

Comment: what I want to do is a css3 animation. In the above fiddle I added the transition css property but still it is not working